# Google maps v3: adding a new map when function 'failure' called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

On the contact page of my site two things can happen:

1. The user has geolocation enabled, and a map (`map-canvas`) will display a route from their location to a predefined location `dest`. This feature works fine.
2. The user doesn't have geolocation enabled or chooses not to allow it. An alert will show (works fine), and some text will be added to the `directions-panel` (works fine). The third thing I want to happen in this scenario is a new map be added to `map-canvas` that is centred on `dest`, this feature doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why.

Code below should give a good representation of the above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;
    var dest = "Unit 20, Tallaght Business Centre, Whitestown Road, Tallaght Business Park, Ireland";//53.282882, -6.383155
    var ourLocation = {lat :  53.282882, lng :  -6.383155}//centre attribute of the map must be a LatLng object and not hardcoded as above

    function initGeolocation() {
       if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, failure );
        }
    }

    //create a new map centered on user's location, display route and show directions
    function success(position) {
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions-panel"));
      calcRoute();
    }

    //calculate the route from user's location to 'dest'
    function calcRoute() {
      var start = coords;
      var end = dest;
      var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
      });
    }

    //tell user geoloc isn't enabled and just plot 'ourLocation' on 'map-canvas'
    function failure() {
        alert("Your browser does not have geolocation enabled so we can't give you directions to our office. Enable geolocation and try again, or consult the map for our address.");
        $("#directions-error-message").css({
          visibility: 'visible'
        });     
        var destMapOptions = {
          zoom:13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(ourLocation.lat, ourLocation.lng)
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), destMapOptions);
    }

    </script>
```

Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working? All help appreaciated.

EDIT: Working version above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the map a LatLng object for it's centre, not an address. You will need to use Googles LocalSearch services to make that work.

```
var dest = {
   lat :  53.282882,
   lng :  -6.383155
}

var destMapOptions = {
    zoom:12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(dest.lat,dest.lng)
}
```

Also, as you have map declared as a var already maybe use that rather than a function scoped variable for the map.

Comment: Thanks that worked. However when I replaced all the `dest` with a the LatLng object you described, the route would not be displayed on the map when `success` was called, so I had to keep `dest` with the harcoded address and create `var ourLocation` as a LatLng object and only use it in `failure` -- it seems to work. Not sure if it was something I was doing or...?

Answer (score 2):

The center attribute of the map options must be a LatLng object.  You've got it hardcoded as an address string.